Solving a complicated equation for approximate analytical solution
I am trying to solve the Following equation for r,
2*a*Q^4 + 5*r^4*(-4*Q^2 - 2*r*(-3*M + r) + 3*c*r^(1 - 3*\[Omega])*(1 + \[Omega])) ==0

Clearly this is unsolvable. But if we substitute a=0 and c=0 we get one of the solutions $r=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{9 M^2-8 Q^2}+3 M\right)$.. Can I obtain approximate analytical solution of the above equation which gives the same value when substitutions a=0 and c=0 are applied. If yes, then how? I have tried AsymptoticSolve, but got no answer.
Thanks in advance.
Edit- The cross-post is here

What are the small parameters which you tried for AsymptoticSolve?

@Nasser I do not want to put values of a and c. Just want to solve the eq analytically. after getting solution I can put those values to check whether my solution is correct or not. a and c can take different values. so first I need to find solution in explicit form, even if it is approximate.

@UlrichNeumann a and c

a,c <<1 small?

parameter \[Omega]1/3?

@UlrichNeumann yes.. a and c are very small but cannot be discarded. omega lies between -1 and -1/3. the solution you have given below does not match the requirement a=c=0 gives $r=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{9 M^2-8 Q^2}+3 M\right)$.

The solution r  is 1/2 (3 M + Sqrt[9 M^2 - 8 Q^2]) + dr /.soldr and matches  quite well I think

@UlrichNeumann yeah that would be fine I guess. I thought the solution is only dr.. okay will try this one. thanks a lot.

Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3182263

@MichaelE2 Is there any problem with the cross-post? Should I delete one of the posts?

@UlrichNeumann Thank you again. This AsymptoticSolve is working very well.

@DebojyotiMondal It gives the same result as the one in the cross-post using AsymptoticSolve (see MichaelE2's comment )

Yes, the cross-post was also posted by me.

No problem with cross-posting, but both sites, SE and community.wolfram, have policies that ask that links to cross posts be included, so that users can follow along. You should edit your questions to include the links.

@MichaelE2 okay, will do that tomorrow.

If you are looking for an analytical approximation  near   r -> 1/2 (3 M + Sqrt[9 M^2 - 8 Q^2]) try
eq = 2*a*Q^4 +5*r^4*(-4*Q^2 - 2*r*(-3*M + r) +3*c*r^(1 - 3*\[Omega])*(1 + \[Omega]))
Asymptotic[eq /. r -> 1/2 (3 M + Sqrt[9 M^2 - 8 Q^2]) + dr, {dr , 0,2}]
soldr=Solve[% , dr]


addendum
With additional information given by QP we can get an asymptotic solution
Assuming: a,c small of same order a->eps a,c->eps c eps->0
Solve[eq == 0 /. {a -> 0, c -> 0}, r] 
solr0 = %[[-1]] (*  only solution r>0:  r -> 1/2 (3 M + Sqrt[9 M^2 - 8 Q^2]) *)
eqeps = eq /. {a -> eps a, c -> eps c}
soleps = Solve[eqeps == 0, eps][[1]] (* eps[r] *)  

Asymptotic[eps /. soleps /. r -> (r /. solr0) + dr, {dr, 0, 1}];
soldr = Solve[% == eps, dr][[1]] /. eps -> 1 // FullSimplify

asymptotic solution ( a,c<<1 )
solr={r -> (r /. solr0) + dr /. soldr}


